Issue with Wireless Network Connection on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Hello Ubuntu community,
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS onto a USB drive using an MSI machine. However, I'm encountering difficulties with connecting to the wireless network. Ubuntu doesn't recognize any wireless networks, whereas I can successfully connect to the internet on Windows. Currently, I'm able to use a wired connection on Ubuntu.
I'm a beginner and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this issue. Below are some relevant pieces of information:
Relevant Information
lspci -k
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169, r8125
05:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Technologies, Inc WCN785x Wi-Fi 7(802.11be) 320MHz 2x2 [FastConnect 7800] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. High Band Simultaneous Wireless Network Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: ath12k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath12k

ifconfig
enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.107  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::da43:aeff:fe0b:414b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d8:43:ae:0b:41:4b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 469  bytes 263903 (263.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 405  bytes 56774 (56.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 185  bytes 15956 (15.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 185  bytes 15956 (15.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 05
       serial: d8:43:ae:0b:41:4b
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-31-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8125b-2_0.0.2 07/13/20 ip=192.168.1.107 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:41 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fc900000-fc90ffff memory:fc910000-fc913fff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: WCN785x Wi-Fi 7(802.11be) 320MHz 2x2 [FastConnect 7800]
       vendor: Qualcomm Technologies, Inc
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ath12k_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:108 memory:fc200000-fc3fffff

Attempts Made
I attempted to download drivers from the Realtek website, including r8169 and r8125, but they didn't seem to work (Realtek Downloads, Realtek Downloads). I also tried searching for drivers on the Qualcomm website, but couldn't find any.
Any assistance or guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Relevant Information Added in 2024.5.10
sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager
May 10 15:09:44 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF systemd[1]: Starting NetworkManager.service - Network Manager...
May 10 15:09:45 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324985.8412] NetworkManager (version 1.46.0) is starting... (boot:2f785b24-7fd9-4fa3-bf2e-2e173d5a3ae4)
May 10 15:09:45 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324985.8459] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (run: 10-globally-managed-de>
May 10 15:09:45 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324985.9116] manager[0x5a4848d9b810]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
May 10 15:09:45 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324985.9117] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
May 10 15:09:45 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324985.9146] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
May 10 15:09:45 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324985.9147] hostname: static hostname changed from (none) to "larry-Alpha-17-C7VF"
May 10 15:09:45 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324985.9176] dns-mgr: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=unmanaged (auto), plugin=systemd-resolved
May 10 15:09:45 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324985.9183] manager[0x5a4848d9b810]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
May 10 15:09:45 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324985.9183] manager[0x5a4848d9b810]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
May 10 15:09:45 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324985.9579] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
May 10 15:09:45 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324985.9635] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
May 10 15:09:46 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324986.0838] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
May 10 15:09:46 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324986.1100] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
May 10 15:09:46 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324986.1230] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
May 10 15:09:46 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324986.1232] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
May 10 15:09:46 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324986.1232] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
May 10 15:09:46 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324986.1232] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
May 10 15:09:46 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324986.1534] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.46.0/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
May 10 15:09:46 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324986.1535] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
May 10 15:09:46 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324986.1535] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
May 10 15:09:46 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324986.1596] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
May 10 15:09:46 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF generate[1686]: Permissions for /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.
May 10 15:09:46 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324986.8594] dhcp: init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
May 10 15:09:46 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324986.8595] manager: (lo): new Loopback device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
May 10 15:09:46 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324986.8600] device (lo): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 10 15:09:46 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324986.8602] device (lo): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 10 15:09:46 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324986.8604] device (lo): Activation: starting connection 'lo' (2d4af236-db73-4ce7-bcd9-9baac19a348d)
May 10 15:09:46 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324986.8609] manager: (enp4s0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
May 10 15:09:46 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324986.8610] device (enp4s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 10 15:09:47 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324987.0566] failed to open /run/network/ifstate
May 10 15:09:47 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324987.0569] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
May 10 15:09:47 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF systemd[1]: Started NetworkManager.service - Network Manager.
May 10 15:09:47 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324987.0573] device (lo): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 10 15:09:47 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324987.0574] device (lo): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 10 15:09:47 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324987.0575] device (lo): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 10 15:09:47 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324987.0577] device (lo): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 10 15:09:47 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324987.0582] modem-manager: ModemManager available
May 10 15:09:47 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324987.0589] device (lo): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 10 15:09:47 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324987.0589] device (lo): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 10 15:09:47 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324987.0591] device (lo): Activation: successful, device activated.
May 10 15:09:53 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324993.0564] manager: startup complete
May 10 15:09:54 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324994.2185] agent-manager: agent[7e974a7dc47e03cb,:1.36/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/120]: agent registered
May 10 15:10:07 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715325007.4870] agent-manager: agent[defb4cf0828c9331,:1.79/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered

service NetworkManager status
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-05-10 15:09:47 CST; 10min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 1557 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 18099)
     Memory: 17.2M (peak: 33.7M)
        CPU: 196ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─1557 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

May 10 15:09:47 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324987.0574] device (lo): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 10 15:09:47 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324987.0575] device (lo): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 10 15:09:47 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324987.0577] device (lo): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 10 15:09:47 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324987.0582] modem-manager: ModemManager available
May 10 15:09:47 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324987.0589] device (lo): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 10 15:09:47 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324987.0589] device (lo): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
May 10 15:09:47 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324987.0591] device (lo): Activation: successful, device activated.
May 10 15:09:53 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324993.0564] manager: startup complete
May 10 15:09:54 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715324994.2185] agent-manager: agent[7e974a7dc47e03cb,:1.36/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/120]: agent registered
May 10 15:10:07 larry-Alpha-17-C7VF NetworkManager[1557]: <info>  [1715325007.4870] agent-manager: agent[defb4cf0828c9331,:1.79/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered

service --status-all
[ + ]  alsa-utils
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ - ]  apache-htcacheclean
 [ + ]  apache2
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  apport
 [ + ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  console-setup.sh
 [ + ]  cron
 [ + ]  cups
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ + ]  gdm3
 [ - ]  grub-common
 [ + ]  kerneloops
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.sh
 [ + ]  kmod
 [ + ]  openvpn
 [ - ]  plymouth
 [ + ]  plymouth-log
 [ + ]  procps
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ - ]  saned
 [ - ]  speech-dispatcher
 [ - ]  spice-vdagent
 [ - ]  sssd
 [ + ]  sysstat
 [ + ]  ufw
 [ + ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  uuidd
 [ - ]  whoopsie
 [ - ]  x11-common


2024.7.14
Thank you, Matt Wyllie, and everyone who offered advice. My issue has been resolved. Due to final exams, I only recently had the time to address this.
Following the instructions in the "Upgrade Ubuntu kernel version" section at https://sypalo.com/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu, I downloaded and installed the latest kernel packages:
cd /tmp
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/v6.9.9/amd64/linux-headers-6.9.9-060909_6.9.9-060909.202407111135_all.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/v6.9.9/amd64/linux-headers-6.9.9-060909-generic_6.9.9-060909.202407111135_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/v6.9.9/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-6.9.9-060909-generic_6.9.9-060909.202407111135_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/v6.9.9/amd64/linux-modules-6.9.9-060909-generic_6.9.9-060909.202407111135_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo reboot

After rebooting, I encountered a "bad shim signature" error. By disabling the Secure Boot option in the BIOS security settings, I resolved the issue, and my wireless connection is now working fine.

Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager. Read man journalctl NetworkManager service. Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.

Thanks, advise 2024.7.14 works for me

I have the same issue with my TPLINK wifi dongle that uses the generic rtl8821au driver. Every distro upgrade ends up with the same annoying issue. The kernel upgrade breaks the compiled driver module, and it needs to be downloaded from github for the new kernel version, it has to be recompiled and reinstalled.
The trick is getting the correct driver from github, which given the abundance of drivers, is not an easy task.
The one that did it for me is:
https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708
Just download into /usr/src, cd into the driver directory, and run the installation shell script.
sudo git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708.git into /usr/src
cd into the /usr/src/8821au-20210708 directory, and run the installation script
sudo ./install-driver.sh
You won't even have to reboot. As soon as the installation ends, you'll start seeing networks appear in the networks widget.

you need the latest stable kernel for the wifi 7 card.  Follow these instructions halfway down this page where it says "Upgrade Ubuntu kernel version" - it worked for me:  https://sypalo.com/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu

If there is something in that link needed to answer the question it needs to be in the answer. What about later when the link does not work? You can have the link for reference but please include the info in your answer.
